# Force correct weapon switching, when switching to shield?

Tags: dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic

I recently started playing Dark Messiah of might and magic again, now the problem I seem to be having that when I switch from a weapon without shield to a weapon with shield, it automatically equips the hammer in my inventory instead of equipping my longsword.

Is there a way to force the game to use the weapon I want when switching to a shield?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the game binds some weapon to always be equipped with the shield. For me, "Long Sword" (3 damage) is always selected over the superior "Sword of the Disciple" (5 damage, next to the shield). Inventory order has no effect in the game's selection.
I tried throwing weaker one-hand weapons away, but then the game doesn't equip the shield *at all* unless you have a sword in hand. Your only option is to equip the weapon you intend to use with the shield **first**, it seems.

[image: Dark Messiah ui]

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this bug, **throw away your hammer, then throw away all shields, equip favorite sword, then pick up shields, last pick up the hammer**.

You should now be able to quick-inventory the shield and get the sword you chose, plus keep the hammer, no patches needed.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do that is to change the order of your weapons. That way the game will recognize on of your weapons as a "primary" weapon.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried it in the hotbar, I tried it in the inventory. It always takes out the damned hammer.

Comment: would you please post a screen shot so i can help you further?

Comment: I will tonight when I get home from work, ill just give you the bounty because it will be deleted anyway ;)

Comment: @Lyrion I would like to try and help you, not just take a bounty. Could you post a screen shot of your problem?

Comment: I can confirm that the game arbitrarily chooses the weapon to be used with a shield, ordering the menu has no effect.